# How to add attributes about AWS resources to a Grafana panel

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana

The [Amazon CloudWatch datasource](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/) allows the specification of filters like [ec2_instance_attributes](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/template-variables/#use-ec2_instance_attribute) that allow the retrieval of information about EC2 instances. I couldn't find the same for EBS volumes or other resources.

Is there a way to retrieve parameters about AWS resources so they can be added to a panel?